# c# dynamic event subscription and unsubscription

Tags: c#, dynamic, eventhandler

I want to be able to have an object add one of its methods to an `EventHandler` that is passed to it and give said method the ability to remove itself from the `EventHandler`.

```
public class EventRaiser {
    public event EventHandler event1
    public event EventHandler event2
    public void fire() {
        event1?.Invoke(this, null);
        event2?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}

public class EventSubscriber {
    EventHandler eh;
    public EventSubscriber(EventHandler eh) {
        this.eh = eh;
        eh += receive;
    }

    public void receive(object obj, EventArgs data) {
        // Do stuff.
        if(condition) eh -= receive;
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public void Main() {
        EventRaiser er = new EventRaiser();
        EventSubscriber es1 = new EventSubscriber(er.event1);
        EventSubscriber es2 = new EventSubscriber(er.event2);
        er.fire();
    }
}
```

The above code does not compile as I cannot even pass `er.event1` or `er.event2` to `EventSubscriber` ("The event can only appear in the left hand side of +=..."). Removing the `event` keyword from the `EventHandler`s fixes this issue but unsubscribing does not work properly. Is there a way to make this work? Use pointers maybe?

Comment: I don't think you should or even can pass around the event itsself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here comes from you passing an `EventHandler`, not the list holding the `delegate`s behind it itsself. Basically the "list of method pointers" to your handlers.

As you can see, in the declaration of `event1` you have the keyword `event`, which is missing when you pass it somewhere else.
Unfortunately you cannot extract the "`delegate` holder" of an `event` easily.

Basically at the time you want to register your handler to an event you somehow need a compile time reference to it, in order to be able to `+=` and `-=` to it.

You could do the following:

```cs
public class EventRaiser
{
    public delegate void Event1(string args);
    public List<Event1> handlers = new List<Event1>();

    public void register(Event1 handler)
    {
        handlers.Add(handler);
    }

    public void unregister(Event1 handler)
    {
        handlers.Remove(handler);
    }
    
    public void fire()
    {
        handlers.ForEach(handler => handler("myEventArgs"));
    }
}
```

```cs
public class EventSubscriber
{
    Action<Event1> registerAction;
    Action<Event1> unregisterAction;
    public EventSubscriber(Action<Event1> register, Action<Event1> unregister)
    {
        registerAction = register;
        unregisterAction = unregister;
        registerAction(receive);
    }

    public void receive(string args)
    {
        // Do stuff.
        unregisterAction(receive);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class MainClass
{
    public void Main()
    {
        EventRaiser er = new EventRaiser();
        EventSubscriber es1 = new EventSubscriber(er.register, er.unregister);                
        er.fire();
    }
}
```